# how to sum all values in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

My table value is:

```
id stock
1   7|8
2   80|50|30
```

and my query is

I used PHP function

```
function numofQuantity() {

    $sql = "SELECT sum(stock) as quantity FROM products";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $data['quantity'];

}
```

Here it shows the result is 87.

How to sum all the values? Thank you

Comment: Instead of fixing this, you should rather normalize your database so you can actually run SUM(stock) on there. You should have one column for ID, and one for each stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is difficult to do in Mysql. You can do it php like below:

```
function numofQuantity() {

    $sql = "SELECT stock FROM products";
    $result = dbQuery($sql);
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $arrayVal = explode("|", $data['stock']);
    return array_sum($arrayVal)

}
```

For more info :https://www.php.net/array_sum

Answer (score 4):

### Never store multiple values in one column!

As you see now that will only lead to problems. You should rather change your DB design. Use another table to store the stock:

```
stock table
-----------
id
product_id
stock
```

The you could sum the stock like this

```
SELECT p.id, sum(s.stock) as quantity 
FROM products p
inner join stock s on s.product_id = p.id
group by p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should **normalize** your database if you wish to do anything with the individual values inside a column.

Without normalization you will need the support of PHP ([PDO](http://php.net/pdo) example):

```
$sum = 0;
$res = $db->query('SELECT stock FROM products');
foreach ($res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $stocks) {
    $sum += array_sum(explode('|', $stocks));
}

echo $sum;
```